# 405 Not Allowed nginx phpmailer

Tags: php, nginx, phpmailer, http-status-code-405

I have just uploaded a page and find out the phpmailer isn't sending emails though it was sending in localhost. Getting 405 Not Allowed nginx. Any help? following is the code...

```
if (isset($_POST['msg_submit'])) {                                                  

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                            
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
    $mail->Host = $smtp_server_w;                   
    $mail->Username = $username_w; 
    $mail->Password = $password_w;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom("test@gmail.com", "test");

    $sql_mail = "SELECT * FROM order_details ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    $run_mail = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_mail);
    while ($row_mail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_mail)) {
        $mail->addAddress($row_mail['user_email'], $row_mail['user_name']);   

        $mail->isHTML(true); 

        $bodyContent = message;
        $mail->Subject = test message ;
        $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
        $mail->AltBody = $bodyContent;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Message could not be sent.";
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo.'</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-default"><strong>Message has been sent</strong></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an nginx config issue, not your script.

Comment: Thanks Synchro... So how should I resolve it? Is it from hosting service? currently, I am using gmail smtp to send email....

Comment: what is your nginx configuration ? check in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled